# Installation error in 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I tried installing using both USB and DVD but its showning the same error again and again: `error in installation` it may be due to CD/DVD damage or may be due faster burning of CD/DVD so thought burning with slower speed may solve the problem or run in cooler environment and something else.

I tried with 11.10 by the same procedure it worked, but not with 12.04. I've the ISO file.

What should i do? I am a great fan of ubuntu and wanna use the latest version as soon as possible. Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ISO you downloaded wasn't corrupted during the download. You can do this by downloading the MD5SUM list from http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/MD5SUMS to the same directory as the ISO you downloaded, then running

```
md5sum -c MD5SUM
```

If the sums do not match, then it is corrupt and you will need to redownload the ISO. If the sums do match, then you might try burning the CD at a slower speed or using a USB instead of a CD.